# Flag for watching files with iron-node

Tags: iron-node

The **iron-node** introduction on **github** mentions watching files:

"I hated attaching processes, watching files..".

But I can't for the life of me find any documentation about what flags to use to get **iron-node** to reload the debug session on file change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File watch is not supported by iron-node. You need press Ctrl+R to restart your debug session. This by design and a wanted behavior.